# Can't enable Java for browser

Tags: macos, java

For some reason, whenever I try to enable Java in the browser by clicking on the checkbox "Enable Java content in browser" in the Security tab of the Java control panel, it asks for my password and then promptly unselects my selection.

Does anyone know what is happening?

I have OSX 10.10.4. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled the Oracle JRE to no avail.

Comment: I thought Apple made Java built-in for web browsing

Comment: Yeah, but I thought the Oracle one was supposed to work for that as well?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue. Here's how I resolved it using Terminal commands:

1. Make yourself to root

   `sudo su -`
2. Remove the existing JAVA Runtime (JRE) as well as JDK if any

   `rm -R /Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/`

   `rm -R /Library/Oracle/`

   `rm -R /Library/Java/`

   `rm -R /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/`

   `rm -R ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/`
3. Download and install the latest JAVA versions from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html. You probably need the JRE only. In case local java software stopped working you'd need the JDK too.
4. Open the System Preferences of OS X, click on JAVA -> Security and activate "Enable Java content in browser"

The setting that prevented you from enabling Java content in your browser most probably is in /Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/.